# -15 баллов за непринятый ответ

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Может быть так было и раньше, но я не сталкивался:

[image: Скриншот]

Вот сам вопрос: [Не получается mul](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/492194/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-mul/492212)

Получается, что автор принял собственный ответ, но т.к. он не может получить бонус в репутации за приняты собственный ответ, то, наоборот, другие отвечающие получают минус?

Это как-то совсем не мотивирует. Для меня это не очень критично, но представим такой вариант, что у отвечающего всего пара сотен баллов репутации, и за свой ответ он получит +10 баллов за "палец вверх" и -15 за то что был принят не его ответ, в сумме -5 баллов за все старания.

Еще один вопрос - получит ли -15 тот, кто ответит после того, как ответ был принят? Если нет - то это будет как-то несправедливо к тем кто -15 уже получил, если получит - то это, опять же, демотивирует.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

-15 может быть только если твой ответ был принят и было начислено +15.
При снятии галочки эти 15 снимаются.

Comment: Если это так, тогда понятно. Видимо автор вопроса посчитал свой вопрос более качественным. Тогда вопрос больше по по формулировке "непринятый" в истории репутации.

Comment: Угу, это проблема перевода. Unaccept надо переводить как-то правильнее.